# How to pass two sets of array from look up activity into For each activity and later how to refer these two arrays inside for each loop activity

Tags: azure, foreach, powerbi, azure-data-factory, lookup

I have pipeline which triggers the powerBI refresh from ADF and waits for the results of powerBI refresh and sends an email if refresh was success or failure, now I want to put this pipeline in Foreach loop so it can refresh multiple powerbI workspaces and datasets in a sequential order.

Activities inside my pipeline has takes two values one for workspaceID and datasetID and I need repeat this two Input array's, how to provide two input arrays from a loop up activity which reading the config table in from the db?

My current pipeline looks like this

[image]

This is the URL that reads WorkspaceID and Dataste ID and this needs to read the array of values

[image]

What should I enter in the Item section

[image]

Currently my Look Up activity reads and returns the table like this, how to add multiple Workspace and dataetIDs in this

[image]

[Currently my look up activity reads and returns the table like this, how to add multiple workspace and datasetIDs in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdilD.png)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to instead of having the table be like this:

[image: Current State]

You would instead make the data related like the below image:

[image: Future State]

If you do this then you can do a lookup and you know each row (Item) of the lookup will give you the WorkspaceID and DatasetID you need to perform your refresh.

Here is an example of the pipeline with Lookup and ForEach:

[image: ADF Pipeline]

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try that. However these two parameters are part of bigger config table, which I can't edit. but I will try to create a  query which can read the config table in the format you shared.
However, do you know if, with existing table format that I shared if there is way Item() in foreach can read it in a way that helps to traverse through both workspaceID as well as Dataset ID ?

Comment: If Row 1/2 are always related, and 2/4, and 5/6, and so on, then there probably is a way you could flatten them, but the biggest problem I see is for dataset refreshes you need the workspaceId and the DatasetId, if you try to refresh using a datasetId that's not in the workspace you are referencing (or vice versa) you are going to throw an error. It would be difficult to build it out the way it currently resides. Another option is to do web calls to power BI API to pull down all datasets, and then you could iterate on those.

Comment: Can you post your pipeline JSON?

Comment: Never Mind, I was able to figure out the issue, thank you so much for your suggestions, really appreciate your help

Comment: Sure! Please mark as answer and vote up if this helped you out!